# Return vector position in list r

Tags: r, list, vector, data-manipulation

I am trying to determine the vector where an element is coming from in a list I have created. I'll give a repeatable example here:

```
set.seed(101)
a <- runif(10, min=0, max=100)
b <- runif(10, min=0, max=100)
c <- runif(10, min=0, max=100)
d <- runif(10, min=0, max=100)

information <- list(a, b, c, d)

information.wanted <- mean(do.call(pmax, information))
```

The code to get the information.wanted works just fine. What I am now trying to find is the individual vector in the list where each of the maximum values comes from. For example, value 1 in information.wanted (87.97...) comes from vector b in the information list. I would like to create another piece of code that gives the vector where the information.wanted comes from.

```
> information.wanted
 [1] 87.97957 95.68375 73.19726 93.16344 92.33189 91.34787 82.04361 81.42830 62.20120
[10] 92.48044
```

I have no idea how to do this though. None of the code that I've tried has gotten me anywhere close.

```
postition.of.information.wanted <- ??
```

I'm looking to get something like this. A numeric vector is fine. I can supplement the values in later.

```
> position.of.informaiton.wanted
[1] 2 3 ...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are all values unique?

Comment: Could try `apply(do.call(rbind, information), 2, which.max)` maybe

Comment: Not necessarily. If there is an easier solution assuming that all values are unique then I could try that. The data set is of a large numerical simulation - list contains 13 vectors each with 10,000 elements, so it's certainly possible there will be duplicates in different positions

Comment: `apply(do.call(rbind, information), 2, which.max)` seems to work perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to apply `which.max` to each "i" index of each element in "information":

```
f1 = function(x)
    sapply(seq_along(x[[1]]), function(i) which.max(sapply(x, "[[", i)))
f1(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

`mapply` already provides that kind of "parallel" functionality:

```
f2 = function(x)
    unlist(.mapply(function(...) which.max(c(...)), x, NULL))
f2(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

Or, instead of concatenating "information" in chunks, convert to a "matrix" -as David Arenburg notes in the comments- at start and `apply` `which.max` to its rows:

```
f3a = function(x)
    apply(do.call(cbind, x), 1, which.max)
f3a(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

or its columns:

```
f3b = function(x)
    apply(do.call(rbind, x), 2, which.max)
f3b(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

also, `max.col` is convenient for a "matrix":

```
f4 = function(x)
    max.col(do.call(cbind, x), "first")
f4(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

If it wasn't R, then a simple loop over the elements would provide both `which.max` and `max` ...but R, also, handles vectors:

```
f5 = function(x)
{
     ans = rep_len(1L, length(x[[1]]))
     maxs = x[[1]]
     for(i in 2:length(x)) {
         wh = x[[i]] > maxs
         maxs[wh] = x[[i]][wh]
         ans[wh] = i 
    }
    ans #or '(data.frame(i = ans, val = maxs)' for both
}
f5(information)
# [1] 2 3 2 2 3 4 2 4 1 4
```

It had to end with a benchmark:

```
set.seed(007)
dat = replicate(13, runif(1e4), FALSE)

identical(f1(dat), f2(dat))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f2(dat), f3a(dat))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f3a(dat), f3b(dat))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f3b(dat), f4(dat))
#[1] TRUE
identical(f4(dat), f5(dat))
#[1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(f1(dat), f2(dat), f3a(dat), f3b(dat), f4(dat), f5(dat), do.call(pmax, dat), times = 50)
#Unit: microseconds
#               expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval  cld
#            f1(dat) 274995.963 298662.210 339279.948 318937.172 350822.539 723673.972    50    d
#            f2(dat)  94619.397 100079.205 114664.776 107479.127 114619.439 226733.260    50   c 
#           f3a(dat)  19767.925  23423.688  26382.919  25795.499  29215.839  40100.656    50  b  
#           f3b(dat)  20351.872  22829.997  28889.845  25090.446  30503.100 140311.058    50  b  
#            f4(dat)    975.102   1109.431   1546.571   1169.462   1361.733   8954.100    50 a   
#            f5(dat)   2427.665   2470.816   5299.386   2520.755   3197.793 112986.612    50 a   
# do.call(pmax, dat)   1477.618   1530.166   1627.934   1551.046   1602.898   2814.295    50 a
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, and for adding the benchmark. Very helpful!